# Ford Fusion (uk) 1.4 TDCi power loss (revs top out early, loses speed on hills).. MAF? EGR? Turbo?

Tags: ford, smoke, fusion, power-loss, tdci

Latest update (5th March):
Okay, so a friend and his mechanic friend with full diagnostic on his computer was able to take a look at the info from diagnostics, and also took a physical inspection on the engine. 
Physical inspection, immediately could say the turbo was done. Tonnes of play on the blades at compressor side (I've now felt a working turbo and realise it really should be solid!). 
It was also apparent the engine seemed to be starting on fewer than the full 4 cylinders. Diags revealed two injectors required (forgot the cylinder numbers for now)..
Sourced a used turbo from local peugeot scrappers (engine is PSA, same as 1.4 HDi) for £60. Waiting to obtain some used injectors and find out whether it is imperative to replace the oil feed, uptake, return, and sump..
Once the work is done, I'll post a final answer on this in case it is of use to anybody else!

update (1st march 2019):
Replaced the EGR valve... original problem still persists just the same although the EGR was very dirty (soot/dried oil?) inside, the gasket was covered in wet oil. Of the two screws that hold the EGR in place, the higher one was clean and dry, the lower one was covered in oil..

Update on below:
This problem is coming up with P0404 EGR fault code. 
I could replace the EGR (can get one for £100 while Eurocarparts have offer)..
But I've read around and some word of this possibly being more fundamentally caused by turbo issues, perhaps intake leak. There is oil on hoses near the turbo intake....

---

Original post:

So this is my Ford Fusion, so basically Fiesta engine, 1.4 TDCi, 2007.

Completely out the blue, I got on the motorway on Sunday and realised the power wasn't right, then after getting up to 50/60 on flat/downhill... on an uphill stretch the power was lacking such that I began slowing.. Fifth gear with foot to floor would usually give increasing power here, but it was struggling, and dropping a gear barely helped. Now, the car starts okay, idles smoothly, and on flat pulls away sluggish but steadily for urban use. Any slight uphill and pulling away is a struggle to reach 25/30mph in reasonable time. When I'm putting acc pedal down fully, often getting a lot of fine white smoke from exhaust.

Parked in neutral, putting the acc pedal to the floor has been topping out at 2.5k-3k rpm, again with smoke and a not so nice noise.

I'm struggling to tell if I'm getting turbo spooling or not... the noise is distracting from what I'm used to hearing anyway.

The air filter was really neglected so replaced that, but obviously that alone wasn't it. A few months back I replaced the fuel filter. I know I was a bit lazy in bleeding it and mostly spent ages priming it from empty using the primer bulb. A rough first start, and a couple of misses in the first drive after, but since then it has been fine. I can't see why any issue with that would suddenly become so catastrophic 3 months later, overnight pretty much.

Haven't been to the EGR yet... took the MAF sensor off, cleaned it with carb cleaner before realising that is a bit risky perhaps... but after letting it dry and reattaching, no difference at all to the drive. Driving it down the street with the MAF sensor unplugged gives no apparent difference to the drive, although unplugging it with engine running gave a very very subtle change in engine noise. Could that mean its gone, hence unplugging it makes no difference? (Alas, and blasting it with 30% hydrocarbon cleaner didn't either).

I took off the turbo IC air intake (between MAF and turbo) hose too... its a bit oily inside, and that smaller side hose leading off towards air filter area - some video called it an oil evaporator - well, that was oily, inside and out, and the connection it plugs into near the air filter was clogged with very solid oily gunge.

I'm not used to turbos, but would the MAF/air intake side be the condenser end? Either way, this is what it looked like inside...
Obviously a bit oily, but I can't tell if the shape of the fins is morphed or totally fine.
[image: inside exposed turbo fins]

The MAF or EGR I can do myself, but even with a sale at eurocarparts either one will still be a hundred quid in parts.. turbo, I can find a used turbo and I suppose I could replace it myself - although I know really doing so I should also replace a tonne of other parts.

Finally, the car has always had a very slow oil leak... with a lot of oil near the turbo and that intake pipe. I'd seen other posts about this, suggesting perhaps spraying from the turbo... or perhaps some seep from that super oily hose leading off from the elbow in the turbo air intake hose...

I'll update if I can get any error codes that give insight, or if I find a solution! But appreciate any pointers as I've done next to no work on this car, on any turbo diesels before, and experience is a bit limited anyway!

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Getting the codes would be a big help here. Second, your description of the noise you're hearing is lacking. If you could either include a video (I know they don't tell all) and what exactly you are talking about as far as the noise goes, it would be a great service. Right now, it sounds like you have an intake leak on the cold side charge piping somewhere, but really not sure.

Comment: Hi Paulster2, thanks for the heads up. I got a code reader, one trouble code on system which was EGR. I cleared it as I have no clue how historic that is (engine light has been on since high-rev misfiring before fuel filter change), and realise there was perhaps a code or more detail which i now can't get to until the code comes back up. As yet, no trouble code has re-appeared, despite several problems over a 2 mile drive.

Comment: also the noise - it just feel clankier and rattlier, generally, than the thicker, deeper diesel engine noise i'm used to. i'm finding it hard to pin down what exactly is different. the egine seems to heat up more quickly than it has in the past... 
I was sat at some lights earlier and intermittently the revs did begin to drop at idle a little and give some wobble to things, then pulling away with a thin white smoke cloud behind me. i'll try to make a video and stick it on youtube or something, but again the noise isn't a really overt diagnostic sound like knocking, just subtle change to usual

Comment: A fresh trouble code: P0404 EGR has flagged up...

Comment: I don't know if it's the same with Fusions, but my partner had a faulty EGR replaced on a 2011 Focus TDCI and it was replaced by a non-Ford part (by the local Ford dealer!), The P0404 code returned a few miles later. The dealer replaced the EGR with a second non-Ford EGR with same result. Finally replacing this with a genuine Ford EGR all was well. I have read of similar issues with others regarding non-Ford OEM EGRs and it seems to be fairly common.

Comment: The EGR could be affected by all the oil your turbo added to the combustion air. sounds like you may need to replace both. Does the turbine wheel of the turbo have a lot of play?

Comment: thanks for the input regarding non-ford parts...
also, yes.. got to the turbo again and there is a lot of play (not sure what is normal but it feels really quite loose to the touch).

also, there is the large, main air intake to the turbo (coming from the MAF sensor and air filter behind that), and then at the elbow between the MAF and the turbo, that wide hose has a narrower hose leading to a rigid connector above the main engine head... i wondered what exactly that is? the connector, and pipe, are both heavily covered inside with oil.. oil evaporator or something I think i heard?

Comment: Just an update... I replaced the EGR valve today, no improvement to the problem..
the higher screw holding the EGR was clean and dry, the lower screw was covered in oil.. EGR itself was really blackened and dirty inside..the gasket was covered in wet oil.
i'm now thinking turbo... can get a new (remanufactured) one from eurocarparts for about £330 while they have an offer on. i can't think what else it could possibly be, and there is a lot of play on the blades at the intake side of the turbo... but weary about throwing over £300 more at it if unsure :/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my fiesta, try to clean out your egr and get a cheap used replacmemt and only change the electrical side that should get rid of the error.
When it comes to the noise I found if you move the breather box the pipe that goes behind the engine if its loose it will make the engine sound a lot deeper so be sure to check that.
When it comes to the turbo i was thinking it might be the wastegate or the hot side might ve clogged up? Worth while yaking it out and having a look thats hoing to be my next step trouble shooting this problem but you'd should be aware that it might be the injector after all